# Create updatable VIEW from two tables with Triggers

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating an android application that uses from sqlite database and ...

I have problem with logic of my database. I have two tables as below:

**TBL_First**

id (int), first_name (text), first_qty (int)

**TBL_Second**

id (int), second_name (text), second_qty (int)

Each table will be used in separate activity.

Qty columns of each table has **0** default value and users can change it at run-time.

Also, I have an final activity that will shows items of **TBL_First** & **TBL_Second** where qty columns

of these tables are **bigger than 0**.

I've use **TBL_Final** for my new activity as below:

```
INSERT INTO "TBL Final"(final_name, final_qty)
SELECT first_name,first_qty FROM "TBL_First" WHERE first_qty > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT second_name,second_qty FROM "TBL_Second" WHERE second_qty > 0
```

I can fetch data of **TBL_final** and show its data to users, but if users want to update **final_qty**, **first_qty** or

**second_qty** doesn't update!

I think that I can use **VIEW** instead of **TBL_Final**, but I know that it would not be updated!

I searched around this issue and found out that **Triggers** can be helpful.

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with **VIEW** and **Trigger** at all !

Just I know I can use **VIEW** as below but I don't know how can I use **Triggers** to update **view_qty**

and **first_qty** and **second_qty** !!!

```
create or replace view final_view (view_name,view_qty) as
select first_name,first_qty where first_qty > 0
union all
select second_name,second_qty where second_qty > 0
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated ...

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Do you mean that If there is any update to first_qty or second_qty AFTER they have been inserted into TBL Final then it is not being reflected in TBL Final and hence in Final Activity?

Comment: No, My mean is when I want update qty of TBL_Final, qty column of TBL_First or TBL_Second must be updated.

Answer (score 0):

The trigger has access to the old and new values of the view's row with the OLD and NEW table aliases; it must use them to look up the row(s) of the base tables:

```
CREATE TRIGGER final_view_update
INSTEAD OF UPDATE OF view_qty ON final_view
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE first_qty
      SET first_qty = NEW.view_qty
      WHERE first_name = NEW.view_name;
    UPDATE second_qty
      SET second_qty = NEW.view_qty
      WHERE second_name = NEW.view_name;
END;
```

The trigger always executes two UPDATEs, but only one WHERE clause will match.

Comment: Tanks for your reply. I think SQLite doesn't support aliasing view, isn't it ? Because I can't create view like my question ...

Comment: What do you mean with "aliasing view"?